# You Tube API - Process for Creating OAuth for Users

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api

Weird, just discovered that any question beginning with the word "You" is marked as "subjective" by SO. Anyway...

I have an app that uses the Python Google API client to connect to YouTube. Up to now, I have used it mostly for personal purposes, so I've been fine with using the standard OAuth procedure for people with developer accounts (the keys aren't real. try 'em -- I dare ya):

```
USERID = '63213491243299.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    KEY = '5hraer8afuda0sf3afeawwoaFCKyJ'
    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
    AGENT = 'Mind Reading Algorithm'

FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
client_id=USERID,
client_secret=KEY,
scope=SCOPE,
user_agent=AGENT)

storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

return build(serviceName='youtube', version='v3', http=http)
```

This works fine, but what if I want to distribute the program as a command line tool? I'd like to simply be able to ask a user for their youtube username and password and connect to the API from there, storing the credentials in a DAT so they don't have to reinsert their password every time. Is there a way to achieve this easily using the Google client wrapper? Their OAuth documentation is.... less than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can not store user's passwords and there is no API to get access with a username-password.
But you can store OAuth token, so user won't need to enter password all the time.

You will see in the examples here, you store a refresh OAuth token in a json file.

"https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/my_uploads.py"